# Preg_replace is not working correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So here is my string:

```
$tmpl = "...TABLE __? (`id` int(11...."
```

And here is a preg_replace:

```
$tmpl = preg_replace('/([^"\'0-9a-z_])__([a-z_]+[^"\'])/i', "\$1".$this->config->db_prefix2."\$2", $tmpl);
```

*By the way **$this->config->db_prefix2** is equal to "**list_**"*

But when the code executes, preg_replace does nothing(leaves everything without changes). It seems to me, that the problem is in preg_replace regular expression. The idea is to
replace __? to list_?.

Comment: it works fine, it's probably your pattern that is wrong...

Comment: Oh, I meant pattern.. Without question mark it works perfectly, but with it no..

Comment: The question mark is a special character in Regx, so you have to escape it.  It means, `optional` or `non-greedy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why you have such a complex pattern when you can just do this

```
 $tmpl = str_replace('__?', $this->config->db_prefix2, $tmpl);
```

Or if you have to use preg_replace

```
 $tmpl = string_replace('/__\?/', $this->config->db_prefix2, $tmpl);
```

You can test it here

https://regex101.com/r/pufIoY/1

also don't blame be because you left the table name out

> $tmpl = "...TABLE __? (`id` int(11...."

That said, If I was templating this, I would use something like this

```
CREATE TABLE {DbPrefix}.{Table} ( id int(11...."
```

And then just use, `str_replace('{DbPrefix}', $prefix )`.  Mainly because it's more readable then `__?`.   But it's your party.

Comment: Well, idk why did I use preg, if str_replace is so simple.. Thanks:)

Comment: Over thought it, easy to do.